# How to convert nested dict of dict to nested OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary

Having a requirement to convert nested dict of dict to nested ordered dict

```
user_dict = {"a": {"b": {"c":
                              {'d': 'e',
                              'f': 'g',
                              'h': 'i'
                              }}}}
```

Expected output:

```
cfg_opts = OrderedDict([('a', OrderedDict([('b', OrderedDict([('c', OrderedDict([('d', 'e'), ('f','g'), ('h', 'i')]))]))]))])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: was trying to nested loop and check if value is isinstance(dict) then created ordereddict

Answer (score 2):

I would use recursive function for this task as follows

```
import collections
user_dict = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'e', 'f': 'g', 'h': 'i'}}}}
def orderify(d):
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        return collections.OrderedDict({k:orderify(v) for k,v in d.items()})
    else:
        return d
ordered_user_dict = orderify(user_dict)
print(ordered_user_dict)
```

output

```
OrderedDict([('a', OrderedDict([('b', OrderedDict([('c', OrderedDict([('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g'), ('h', 'i')]))]))]))])
```

Comment: Beat me too it by a few seconds, couldn't think of solutions other than this one. +1